# Generating Non-Isomorphic Graph

Tags: c++, graph, isomorphism

How do you generate non-isomorphic graphs? So given a G(V, E), I need to generate a graph H(V', E') that is not a isomorphic of G.

I know how to generate isomorphic G.
Given G(V, E), where they are represented by integers. You generated a permutation of V and you go through the edges and change the vertex accordingly.

For non-isomorphic graph, changing randomly doesn't guarantee it is NOT isomorphic. I need a way to guarantee that the graph I generate is not isomorphic of G.

The code that I will be using is C++.

Comment: What exactly do you want? If you want to generate a uniformly random graph, then you probably can't do this efficiently. If you want any graph, then either empty or full graph will work. You can come up with many compromise approaches: e.g., if you are ready to exclude some classes of graphs, generate a random graph until you have a different degree distribution (or other metrics) (which happens with high probability). A decent solution would be to solve the problem exactly for very small graphs and use the described heuristic for larger graphs.

Comment: I want to generate two graphs and they cannot be isomorphic to each other. I can generate one graph but when I generate the second one, it may or may not be isomorphic.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't answer my question. By itself, word "generate" is ambiguous. Would generating an empty graph and a full graph suffice? If not, then you should describe formally what you expect from them. Check my first comment for a possible heuristic.

Comment: The way I am generating the graph is that the input will be number of vertex and number of edges. The number of vertex, right now, is between 5 to 7 and the number of edges are |V|!/2 +/- 2. After this first graph is generated, a second graph need to be generated with the same number of vertex and edges but not isomorphic to each other. This will be one pair and I will need to generate many more pairs.

Comment: 1) Generate a second graph randomly and check that it's not isomorphic to the first one. Some libraries can do this (eg https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/isomorphism.html, it seems), but it's also straightforward to implement in O(|V|! E) time.
2) https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/29612/114966 - just select two graphs with the required number of vertices/edges from different equivalence classes.